# Rounding float decimal

Tags: python

I'm trying to round my output to only two decimal points. I know this has been answered before, but I've read through the forums and have been stuck on this for a while now.

I've tried using the `round()` function inside the `print()` and even used it as its own variable. I'm using Python 3.8.2 on Replit.

```
height = input("enter your height in meters: ")
weight = input("enter your weight in kg: ")
height1 = float(height)
weight1 = float(weight)
results = float(weight1 / height1 ** 2)
results1 = str(results)
print("Your BMI: " + (round(results1, 2)))
```

Comment: round should be called on the float variable, not in the str one. Try `print(f'Your BMI: {round(results, 2)})`

Comment: You don't need to call `float()` when assigning `results`. When you combine floats, you always get a float.

Comment: Allow me to comment on something you've done right here: only using `round` when you PRESENT the data.  Too many people round their floats before they start computing, and because of the nature of floating point, that almost always makes things worse.  Leave the data in full precision, and round it when you print it to make things easier on the humans.

Comment: @Barmar yes that makes sense, I deleted it and it still functions.

Comment: @vLabayen that works! Thank ya'll both. Did that work because you're printing 'f' representing float?

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for the input Mr. Roberts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're fine up to here:

```
height = input("enter your height in meters: ")
weight = input("enter your weight in kg: ")
height1 = float(height)
weight1 = float(weight)
results = float(weight1 / height1 ** 2)
```

But the next line turns the result into a string (presumably to be able to concatenate it with another string in the print).

You'd want to round it before that:

```
results = round(results, 2)
results = str(results)
print("Your BMI: " + results)
```

Note that you also didn't need to rename the variable, you can just overwrite it.

However, a simpler way of achieving the same:

```
print(f"Your BMI: {round(results, 2)}")
```

The `f` in front of the string tells modern versions of Python to replace anything in curly braces `{}` with the value of the expression you put in there.

Also note that you keep casting your results to `float()`, even when the result of an expression will already be a float.

A more concise (and arguably better) version of your script:

```
height = float(input("enter your height in meters: "))
weight = float(input("enter your weight in kg: "))
result = weight / height ** 2
print(f"Your BMI: {round(result, 2)}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `results1` is a string, because you defined it as string in your penultimate line of code.

If you want your code to work, you can change your last line for the following:

```
print('Your BMI is', round(float(results1),2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting your results to a string when you save it to results1. The round function requires the input to be a float type variable.

remove the `results1 = str(results)` and simply apply the round to results.